# How to get f-measure in multiclass-multioutput classification in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I have a `multiclass-multioutput` classification problem where I use `randomforest` classifier in sklearn to perform the classification. My code is as follows.

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:5]
y = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,4], [1,1]])
clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 42, class_weight="balanced")
k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
```

I wanted to perform 10-fold cross validation and get the `f-measure` of the classification. I initially tried the following code.

```
scores = cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring = ('f1_weighted'))
```

However, I got the error `ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported`.

Therefore, I tried the following way by manually looping through the folds in the cross validation.

```
cv_f = []
for train_index, val_index in k_fold.split(X, y):
    clf.fit(X[train_index], y[train_index])
    pred = clf.predict(X[val_index])
    f = f1_score(y[val_index], pred)
    cv_f.append(f)
```

However, it did not work too.

It seems like sklearn does not support multiclass-multioutput classification. However, I am pretty sure that there may be other ways of doing this in python.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

### EDIT

I tried the following code.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate, KFold
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:5]
y = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,4], [1,1]])

clf = MultiOutputClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42, class_weight="balanced"))
k_fold = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

scores = cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring=['f1_weighted'])
```

However, I stll get the error as `raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type)) ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported`.

Please let me know a suitable way to solve this issue.

Comment: The problem with your MWE after the edit is that it has more labels (5) than folds for cross-validation (3). This means your model will have to predict labels it has never seen. I updated the answer accordingly once more and I can confirm that it returns the F-score with no errors or warnings. If this updated version still gives you an error, then I believe it cannot be from the code itself.

Comment: @afsharov it works now. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scikit-learn` actually does support `multiclass-multioutput` classification problems. You just need the right module and classifier. Did you know about the [`sklearn.multioutput`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.multioutput) module and e.g. the 
 [MultiOutputClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html)? With them, you can do:

```
import numpy as np
from random import choices
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate, KFold
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:100]
y = np.array(choices([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]], k=100))

clf = MultiOutputClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42, class_weight="balanced"))
k_fold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

scores = cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring=['f1_weighted'])
```

This code will work all fine.

Comment: No, I haven't heard of `multioutputclassifier`. Do you know how to perform cross validation with i and get the results? If so, please let me know :)

Comment: Just updated the answer with code. You can give it a try.

Comment: Be aware that the `StratifiedKFold` would not accept a mutlioutput target. I used `KFold` instead. I hope it doesn't screw things up.

Comment: thanks a lot. sure, I will check the code and will let you know how things went. thank you :)

Comment: Hi, I tried to run your code now. However, I stll get the error as ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported. What is the sklearn version you use? :)

Comment: I tested with version 0.23.1 of sklearn. Which function/statement is the error associated with? And does it say anything more than just multiclass-multioutput is not supported? It should state what it is accepting instead.

Comment: Hi, I mentioned more details in the `EDIT` section of the question, due to the limited space in the comments. Please let me know your thoughts :)